# Plesk and NodeJS: problems with installation

Tags: node.js, plesk, plesk-onyx

In Plesk Onyx I've installed NodeJS by the Extension tab and I've activated it. Plesk tells me NodeJS is installed on path but when I log by SSH as root or an another user and I try to run "nodejs" or "node" command I get the error telling me Node is not installed.

After struggling few hours I decided to try installing node by SSH command line. I followed this tutorial http://sscnet.ch/content/install-nodejs-npm-less-ubuntu-plesk and now node is installed.

The problem now is....node is installed by only for root user! If I try to login by SSH as another system user (created by Plesk when creating a new website) is I try to do "cd /usr/bin/nodejs" I get non-existent directory. 
Can you please help me solving this situation? I would need NodeJS executable to be called and visible to all Linux system users.

Thanks